# How to format a number in GWT with a complex pattern? Ex.: "000-000-000/000"

Tags: gwt

In the [GWT NumberFormat documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/NumberFormat.html), explains how to format numbers.

How do I format a number, on client side, like this: `"000-000.000.000/000"`?

It's a document number, and I need to fill with zeros where is needed, to fit the fixed size.

GWT understand dots and commas as decimal and currency separators. I haven't found in documenttaion how to format using complex patterns.

**Before creating a server side method to solve this**, I would like to see if anyone knows a client side solution using GWT.

Comment: See this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15452994/what-is-the-alternative-for-string-format-in-gwt) may it helps

Comment: This thread [NumberFormat and German Locale](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/hAq8nA5QtjM) might help you that is addressed by @Thomas Broyer

Comment: @Braj represents a document number. Must be filled with zeros to fit the length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One not very elegant (but probably the fastest) way to do this is to just do it yourself:

- Define a `char[]` of the needed total length
- Set the characters that are constant
- Fill in the digits with simple modulus and division operations
- Convert the `char[]` to a `String`

For example:

```java
public static String format(long num) {
    char[] result = new char[19];
    result[ 3] = '-';
    result[ 7] = '.';
    result[11] = '.';
    result[15] = '/';
    result[18] = (char) (num % 10 + 48); num /= 10;
    result[17] = (char) (num % 10 + 48); num /= 10;
    result[16] = (char) (num % 10 + 48); num /= 10;
    result[14] = (char) (num % 10 + 48); num /= 10;
    result[13] = (char) (num % 10 + 48); num /= 10;
    result[12] = (char) (num % 10 + 48); num /= 10;
    result[10] = (char) (num % 10 + 48); num /= 10;
    result[ 9] = (char) (num % 10 + 48); num /= 10;
    result[ 8] = (char) (num % 10 + 48); num /= 10;
    result[ 6] = (char) (num % 10 + 48); num /= 10;
    result[ 5] = (char) (num % 10 + 48); num /= 10;
    result[ 4] = (char) (num % 10 + 48); num /= 10;
    result[ 2] = (char) (num % 10 + 48); num /= 10;
    result[ 1] = (char) (num % 10 + 48); num /= 10;
    result[ 0] = (char) (num % 10 + 48);
    return new String(result);
}
```

Basically, `num % 10` returns the last digit in the number, `+ 48` converts it to the number of the corresponding Ascii character, and `(char)` actually turns it into a character. `num /= 10` (which is the same as `num = num / 10`) then moves to the next digit. With this, the text is built up from the back to the front, starting with the least significant digit.

The following calls:

```java
System.out.println(format(          12345L));
System.out.println(format(123456789024680L));
```

will then output:

```
000-000.000.012/345
123-456.789.024/680
```

(Since I have no idea what digits in your number your 0s are supposed to correspond to and whether you are talking about a whole number or one with a decimal point somewhere (usually there should only be one), this example simply puts the 15 lowest digits of a `long` in the place of your 0s. But it should be straight forward to adjust this code to do what you need. To have it show a decimal, simply multiply by some power of 10 to move the last digit you want to show into the "unit position", e.g. if you want to have 3 digits after the decimal, multiply by 1000, so call the function as `format((long) (number * 1000))` where `number` is your floating point value.)

**Update:**

Here's a shortened and documented version of the code, that most people would probably consider more maintainable: ;)

```java
public static String format(long num) {
    // Create array of characters to hold result
    char[] result = new char[19];
    // Set all characters in array to (char) 0 (not the same as '0'!)
    Arrays.fill(result, (char) 0);
    // Fill in constant symbols
    result[ 3] = '-';
    result[ 7] = '.';
    result[11] = '.';
    result[15] = '/';
    // Run backwards through digits in number 
    for (int i=result.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
        // Only fill places in result array without constant symbols
        if (result[i]==0) {
            // Place digit in result array
            result[i] = (char) (num % 10 + 48);
            // Advance to next digit
            num /= 10;
        }
    }
    // Convert result array to String and return
    return new String(result);
}
```

*Note that the extra `for` and `if` statements in this version will make it run slower than the one above, but unless you are filling a large table with values generated here, it probably doesn't matter much.*

Comment: I'm impressed with your solution, but I would like a easy code to maintain. Are these lines sorted? Or the sort is not important on this solution?

Comment: The only order that matters is how you extract the digits from your number, i.e. the divisions by 10. So, the lines that start with `result[18]` through `result[0]` need to be in that order. But you could easily put the other lines (`result[3, 7, 11, and 15]`) that place the `-`, `.`, and `/` at the "correct" place in the sequence.

Comment: Some people also might consider it easier to maintain to put all these lines that extract the digits from the number into a `for`-loop. Let me post an update to my answer what that would look like.

Comment: @EdPichler One more comment on performance: Javascript does not natively support the numeric type `long`, so GWT actually emulates it using two numbers, which is a bit slow. If you need this function to run *fast*, use `double` instead of `long` in the first line (nothing else needs to change here, but maybe you want to also change it in the rest of your code if possible) and use the non-for-loop version. :)

Comment: thanks for the advices, I'm starting with GWT and enjoying a lot.

Comment: :) GWT is unbelievably amazing. I'm really wondering why the whole world isn't switching to it yet. The more you get into it, the more you realize how truly awesome it is. But there will be some bumps along your road also! But stick with it and the rewards will be plentiful... ;)

Comment: Yes, as in the project page describe: GWT exists to we create really complex browser applications. I totally agree!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is applicable for you but here's our solution to format a telephone number. The format is (### ###-####) and the input string here can be anything...

```
String digits = textValue.replaceAll("\\D+", "");

if (digits.length()>10) {
  digits = digits.substring(0,10);
}

if (digits.length() == 10) {
    setText(digits.substring(0, 3) + " " + digits.substring(3, 6) + "-" + digits.substring(6, 10));
} else {
   // diplay an error message
}
```